# Display data in Textbox from database

Tags: jquery, html, struts, struts2-jquery

I am working on a Transport website where we are asking customer to enter some `data` so that we can process and show them the result. 
Now page used for collecting `data` has more than 200 `text boxes` and our requirement is to give a *"Save for later use"* `button` to the user so that user can come back any time and get the same unfinished page that he left.

Now I am facing difficulty in how to display the unfinished data that user entered in the last login to the same `text box`. I am using Struts 2 and MySQL.

Comment: You can look in to map data structure,I guess.

Comment: Provide unfinished data the same way you'd provide finished. But I guess you are not providing it. So, you have to rewrite your actions and/or JSPs.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: how can i send back the unfinished data back to text box. My requirement is to  populate the same data that user provided during last login but not actually submitted and saved it for later use.